# how do I specify index document in aws s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, indexing

I'm trying to set up my website with aws s3. When I click on the endpoint url, it gives me a 404 error not found saying the key does not exist. In the the bucket, I specified the index document as app.js, since that's what I called it when I created it. I clearly have no idea what I'm doing - please someone help me!

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS code in S3 can be stored, however you won't be able to host it out of S3 directly since S3 only serves static content (so if your webpage is just simple html + javascript, you can host an index.html and have javascript code referenced there that runs client side).

What you will have to do instead is host the NodeJs app in a different manner, possibly using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), [AWS ElasticBeanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) , or [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)